# Execution order javascript - jquery Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, execution

I'm struggling about an issue about Jquery / Javascript execution order in Edge.
This is my scenario.

I'm developing a multiple choice quiz.
User is required to answer to a question within 10 seconds.
The quickest the user answer, the best score the user gains, so I need to retrieve how much time he takes to give the correct answer.
As soon as the user has selected the answer, two events have to occur in this order:

1) the Javascript function named "end" detects how much time user took to answer and populates the hidden field with the relevant value.
2) an ajax call is made to a php file which checks if the answer is correct, updates the database with relevant score and sends back the output to be shown in the #result div, which is located under the form.

The form is something like this:

```
<form name="quiz" id="quiz" method="post">
        <input type="radio" name="question1" id="answer1-1" value="AAA" required  onclick="return end()">
        <input type="radio" name="question1" id="answer1-2" value="BBB" required  onclick="return end()">
        <input type="radio" name="question1" id="answer1-3" value="CCC" required  onclick="return end()">
        <input type="text"  name="time" id="time" hidden  >

</form>

<div id="result"></div>
```

These are Javascript functions which calculate the time to answer.
I cleaned some commands which are unnecessary for this topic.

```
    <script>        
        var count = 1000;
        var counter = setInterval(start, 10); //10 will  run it every 100th of a second

        function start()
        {     
            if (count <= 0 )
            {
                clearInterval(counter);          
            }      
            count--;       
            document.getElementById("boxtime").innerHTML="Time left: " + count/100 + " secs";                     
        }


        function end() {
            document.quiz.time.value=count;
        }
    </script>
```

This is Jquery function, which is called upon the click on the answer option.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#quiz").change(function(){ 
        var dati = $("#quiz").serialize();

        $("#result").html( "" );
         $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                url: "ajax_fetch_result.php",
                data: dati,
                dataType: 'html',
                },
                success: function(html) {    
                    $("#result").html( html );
                }
            });
        //} 
    });
    });
```

This flow woks fine in Chrome, but doesn't work in Internet Explorer Edge because when the user selects his answer, it looks like Jquery function is executed before the Javascript function, so the hidden value in my form is not populated and php file doesn't get the correct value.
What I'm trying to do is to force the execution of Javascript function before Jquery so that the flow can work as expected in Edge as well.

Anyone has some hints?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us the rest of the code? Where is the other function?

Comment: Thanks Aioros. For the sake of clarity, I updated the original post by adding the Javascript functions.

Comment: I solved!
I added this line to Jquery function: $('input[name="time"]').val(count); which populates the hidden field. Hene I do not need anymore the function end().